# TouchableOpacity inside rendered by FlatList renderItem doesn't work

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist, touchableopacity

On working on application where i have the below code

```
 <View style={styles.screen}>
      <GoalInput addGoalHander={addGoalHander} />
      <FlatList
        data={goalsList}
        renderItem={(itemdata) => (
          <GoalItem
            goalText={itemdata.item.value}
            onDelete={() => console.log("it works!")}
          />
        )}
      />
```

GoalItem component:

```
return (
    <TouchableOpacity onPress={props.onDelete}>
      <View style={styles.inputContainer}>
        <TextInput
          placeholder="Start type here..."
          style={styles.toDoTextStyle}
          onChangeText={goalInputHandler}
          value={goalText}
        />
        <Button
          title="Add"
          onPress={props.addGoalHander.bind(this, goalText)}
        />
      </View>
    </TouchableOpacity>
```

the console.log call never worked i can't understand why, anybody had had faced such problem? appreciate if someone can share the solution.

Comment: From where are you importing **TouchableOpacity**? Also can you try **() => {props.onDelete()}**

Comment: from 'react-native, i've tried props.onDelete() no luck :(

Comment: **onPress = {() => {props.onDelete()}}**, like this?

Comment: In the styles above and inside of Flatlist, are you using either of these two, 
1. negative value in margin
2. any absolute position

Comment: @Tarun No Sir, i don't.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that the Button component in the GoalItem component is receiving the onPress event and not the TouchableOpacity. Try commenting out the Button and see if it works.

By the way, may I know why you have

```
onPress={props.addGoalHander.bind(this, goalText)}
```

in the Button component?

```
onPress={()=> addGoalHandler(goalText})
```

may work just fine.